# Selenium Webdriver: Robot Class: Unable to enter numbers in text field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I have a text field into which I need to enter numbers and moving focus out of the field the value in the text field will be auto populated. I have used below code which worked earlier. But, now running / debugging below code don't enter number.

Code:

```
public void dwshortname_and_Contract_number_is_entered() throws Throwable {

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNamenew")).sendKeys("TestUser");

     driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNonew")).sendKeys("");

    Robot robot = new Robot();      
    robot.delay(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_9);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_9);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);        

 }
```

Comment: When I have eclipse opened in debug at line robot.keypress(Keyeven.VK_2). The value is being printed in Eclipse IDE but not in the application text box ? any clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in usage of "SendKeys" which is builtIn in Selenium webdriver and Robot Class.

SendKeys():

This is associated with the driver and the element that the driver is pointing to and hence when you send keys it exactly goes to element and puts in the values (Even though you are debugging using eclipse).

Robot Class:

Robot on the other hand has nothing to do with neither the driver nor the element driver is pointing to. All it knows is to generate keyboard events (which in your case is entering numbers). So when you open eclipse and run through the code, it will actually send key board events to the place where cursor is pointing to which is "eclipse".

Now coming to the issue, you face issues when you try to disturb the execution manually doing some operations. If the whole scripts runs without any manual interaction it should run just fine!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation Waman. . When I don't disturb the execution, the numbers are not entered in the text field .

Comment: you mean entered in text field? or it is still failing?

Comment: execution comes till the line of entering into the text field and its failing there as I said, numbers are not passed to the text field.

Comment: oh it is not entering the string at all? any exception? Sorry am unable to get a clear picture of the issue, hence too many questions

Comment: no.. nothing is getting entered. I'm seeing webdriver element exception error.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139922/discussion-between-waman-and-sowmya lets discuss and close here?

Answer (score 0):

[Robot Example](http://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html)

Nothing in your code jumps out at me except that the example provided on this web page show the sleep method being used between each keystroke.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;   
import java.awt.Robot;  
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;   
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;   

class Excercise1 {  

  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {    
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
       driver.get("http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/C35/P10/"); // sample url  
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@href=contains(text(),'yearly-calendar.xls')]")).click();  
       Robot robot = new Robot();  // Robot class throws AWT Exception  
       Thread.sleep(2000); // Thread.sleep throws InterruptedException  
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);  // press arrow down key of keyboard to navigate and select Save radio button  

       Thread.sleep(2000);  // sleep has only been used to showcase each event separately   
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); 
       Thread.sleep(2000);  
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); 
       Thread.sleep(2000);  
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); 
       Thread.sleep(2000);  
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);   
   // press enter key of keyboard to perform above selected action  
 }
```

}

Comment: I understand the Robot example given above. But in my scenario, the code what I have written worked once but not again when I re-run it.

Comment: Also, let me know how I can enter numbers into text field as it is required for me than key Down and Enter events. Thanks.